# How I can access FaceId or face Recognition in react native for android?

Tags: android, react-native, touch, face-recognition, face-id

I have already tried `react-native-touch-id` package for biometric login. but i couldnot find solution to get access for faceId in android. or face recognition. I have gone through firebase ml kit face recognition but it is has paid plans.

Comment: This is similar to your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74965043/295004) but it is unclear what use case you are trying to achieve. Biometric security is different than face detection.

Comment: Actually I am trying to get true or false when faceId is matched with stored faceId in android phone. 
I have achieved so far is , I have used react-native-touch-id and got true from its authenticate function when I tried with the biometric(finger) stored in phone. Same I want to acheive it for face recogination i.e. faceId